# Merge two sorted arrays into one sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting, matlab

I am trying to write a Matlab function that merges 2 sorted arrays containing integers. The input is 2 arrays, each in ascending order. Function should combine the elements of these arrays and produce an output array such that it contains all the elements of input array in ascending order (including multiplicities) and the output array is also sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Yes.. I am new to Matlab and I am struggling to find an answer :(

Comment: Could you help me with this? I am not able to get a solution to this.. I am new to matlab and programming in general

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach in MATLAB is to [concatenate the two arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html) and [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) them:

```
outArray = sort([in1(:); in2(:)]);
```

However, if you need to create your own merge function without using [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html), you can take advantage of the fact that the input arrays are already sorted. Here's one possible way to do this:

```
function outArray = merge_sorted(in1,in2)
  inAll = [in1(:); flipud(in2(:))];  %# Combine the arrays, flipping the second
  N = numel(inAll);       %# The number of total input values
  iFront = 1;             %# Index for the front of the array
  iBack = N;              %# Index for the back of the array
  outArray = zeros(N,1);  %# Initialize the output array
  for iOut = 1:N                       %# Loop over the number of values
    if inAll(iFront) <= inAll(iBack)   %# If the front value is smaller ...
      outArray(iOut) = inAll(iFront);  %#    ...add it to the output ...
      iFront = iFront+1;               %#    ...and increment the front index
    else                               %# Otherwise ...
      outArray(iOut) = inAll(iBack);   %#    ...add the back value ...
      iBack = iBack-1;                 %#    ...and increment the back index
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. how do I change this to display the array in descending order?

Comment: The fliplr function will reverse an array.

Comment: @Sandeep: As explained in the documentation for [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html), you can add the optional `'descend'` argument.

Comment: Thanks again.. I was just working to write a program for that in matlab without using that function. as in I am also required to implement this in my own program.

Comment: @nibot, can you help me with the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
function MergeTwoSortedArr(){
var arr1 = [23,45,67,89], arr2 = [34,40,50,87];
var temp=[];
var j=0;
var i=0;
while(temp.length ==(arr1.length + arr2.length)){
  if(arr1[i]< arr2[j]){
      temp.push(arr1[i]);
      i=== arr2.length-1?  temp.push(arr1[j]): i++;
  }else{
      temp.push(arr2[j]);
      j=== arr2.length -1 ?  temp.push(arr1[i]): j++;
  }
} 

return temp;

}
```